# como criar uma máscara de moeda com regEx

Tags: angularjs, regex

olá, sou iniciante com angular 4, estou tentando fazer uma mascara para uma campo do tipo texto para validar uma valor em m².

A class Mask contem o método para criar a mascara, o valor informado pode ser entre 1 e ilimitado.

queria que o método retorna-se algo nesse contexto: 1.000.000,00 ou 10.000,00 ou 1.000,00

```js
export class Mask
{

  public static getArea():Array<string|RegExp>
    {

     return [/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'.',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'.',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,',',/\d/,/\d/];

    }
}
```

```html
<input formControlName="areaImovel" [textMask]="{ mask: areaMask }" type="text" id="form-area-imovel" class="form-control">
```

Chamando no Component

```js
import { Mask } from './mask';

export class EnderecoComponent implements OnInit {
  public areaMask = Mask.getArea();
  
  constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema ?

Comment: Tente esta Regex: `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+,\d{2}$` e a [demo na Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NgnQnM/3). Para validação do campo.

Answer (score 1):

Use o dependência do  **ng2-currency-mask**:

1. adicione a dependência no seu projeto:

   ```
   npm i ng2-currency-mask --save
   ```
2. importe no seu modelo o componente:

   ```
   import { CurrencyMaskModule } from 'ng2-currency-mask';
   ```
3. use:

```
<input type="text" id="form-area-imovel" formControlName="areaImovel"
 class="form-control" placeholder="0,00"
 currencyMask [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', allowNegative: false }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei em outro local uma regex para a validação de moeda, `\^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|\d+)(\,\d{2})?$\`.

Para verificar o funcionamento, https://regex101.com/r/VWk35U/2. A expressão aceita estes tipos de valores,

- 1.000.000,00
- 10.000,00
- 1.000,00
- 1042,35
- 100,25
- 999.999.999.999.999.999,00

O site original da regex é, O site é https://precisoestudarsempre.blogspot.com/2014/12/regex-para-validacao-de-moeda.html

Comment: Não precisa escapar a vírgula